# Python array printing in unicode and csv issue

Tags: python, csv, unicode, unicode-string

dict1 is a dictionary with a corresponding array with 4 sample elements like this:

```
{u'OlpyplEJ_c_hFxyand_Wxw': [u'Inchin Bamboo Garden', u'Paradise Valley', 33.575816, -111.926234], 
u'_qvxFHGbnbrAPeWBVifJEQ': [u"Lenny's Sub Shop", u'Charlotte', 35.334993, -80.8129717], 
u's5yzZITWU_RcJzWOgjFecw': [u"Sergio's Italian Gardens", u'Las Vegas', 36.100414, -115.1265829]}
```

I am printing data using the business_id as the key for the above dictionary

```
print "%s,%s" % (dict1[jd['business_id']], re.sub('\n|\r', '', jd['text']))
```

example output is:

```
[u"P&G's Pamela's Diner", u'Pittsburgh', 40.451723, -79.932833], The food here is over the top excessively greasy. So greasy that it made me sick to my stomach before I was done eating my meal. My husband and I split the chocolate chip pancakes and a ham and cheese omelette with potatoes and toast on the side. Not only was everything in a pool of grease, but it seemed to be margarine...not even real butter. I will never eat here again. I am gagging even thinking about this meal let aloe eating it again.
```

I have two problems, the first, how to remove the unicode tag u' from the 2 output strings in the array, i've tried str() but it doesn't work

the second, when i export as a .csv file commas in the 'text' are picked up and it splits it up, i've tried using ' ' around it but again i can't figure it out

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `u` by encoding unicodes by passing `'unicode-escape'` to `unicode.encode()` method . you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=[u"P&G's Pamela's Diner", u'Pittsburgh', 40.451723, -79.932833]
>>> [i.encode('unicode-escape') if isinstance(i,unicode) else i for i in l]
["P&G's Pamela's Diner", 'Pittsburgh', 40.451723, -79.932833]
```

And about your second question its because of that python will assumes the commas as delimiter by default. for get ride of that you can define a costume delimiter for that .

for example :

```
import csv
with open('file_name.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

The "u" denotes a unicode string. You are printing a python array with unicode strings in it, so that's what's being put on the console. Decide what you want have there instead, for example `', '.join(stuff))` would look nice.

For exporting to CSV, I can't help you without seeing your CSV code, but I highly recommend you use Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to handle CSV input and output and choose delimiters that are appropriate to your data.